# Install extensions when creating VSTS account with ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-devops-extensions

I'm using powershell and an ARM template to create a new Team Services account + DevOps Project. Template type: `microsoft.visualstudio/account`

Is there a way to also install [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) via the template or powershell?

I have a couple of extensions I'm always using, It would be nice to automatically have them up and running on new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody stumbles upon this same problem, here's how you can do it with powershell.
After creating the VSTS account, you need to log in and create a personal access token with Extensions (read and manage) in selected scopes.

```
$accountName = "yourAccount"
$personalAccessToken = "your-personal-access-token"

$uri = "https://" + $accountName + ".extmgmt.visualstudio.com/_apis/extensionmanagement/installedextensionsbyname/ms-appinsights/appinsightsreleaseannotations?api-version=5.0-preview.1"

Write-Host "Installing extension: Release Annotations for Azure Application Insights"
Invoke-RestMethod `
-Method Post `
-Uri $uri `
-ContentType application/json `
-Headers @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }
```

Answer (score 1):

thats an interesting question, if this is possible it should be mimicing [this rest call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/install%20extension%20by%20name?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

That is most likely not possible with arm templates. Given this is not under reference on docs and the template says `"operation": "link"` i suppose there is no way of doing that.